# Theme with Isoptope after activation in new install not working well

Tags: theme-development, activation

Hi I'm developing a theme with Isotope (masonry mode) and everything works well in the master/development location of WP. But if I take this theme and I activate it in a new installation of WP (same server, local) something goes wrong.

In this new installation in the inline style of the items appers "display:none" and there is no "right" "top" rules, just "position:absolute" so all the items are stacked up, overlapping one to each other.

I don't know how to debug it, this theme is complex and I would not like to broke another thing trying to fix this. I don't have idea where to start. I would appreciate your help. Maybe some of you have had this problem.

If it could be useful to see, this is the code I use, that is working in the development version.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#isotope').isotope({
        itemSelector : '.frontiles',
        layoutMode : 'masonry',
        filter: '.front-page-tiles',
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: 125,
            gutter:20          }

    });
    $('#filters a.selected').trigger("click");
  $('#filters a, #isotope a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $('#isotope').isotope({ filter: selector });

    $(this).parents('ul').find('a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know what was the issue. I had the filter by category activated in Isotope settings:
    filter: '.front-page-tiles'

:)! so regular items not in that category was being correctly hidden by Isotope